# Blazor, synchronize communication between multiple clients

Tags: http, server, client, blazor

I´ve got a pretty simple small blazor WASM app, where I am programming a game for multiple players. So now my problem is, that all players should of course see, if one player plays a card. I was wondering, if I could use a singleton-service for it. Is this service the same for all clients (one object for all clients) or only for one client? I don´t know exactly how this works. Because if it were one object for all clients, I could just make them subscribe to an event in a service. 
If it is not one service for all clients, is it possible to write a method client side being invoked from server side? Similar to httpClient, something like httpServer probably?
Or do I need to check the status client side manually every second? This would be a bit ugly, due to polling.
You would help me a lot, if you share your experience with such problems. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to implement a real time communication library so you can keep all your clients updated. For AspNetCore, the flagship product is SignalR which now has native Support for blazor.

Go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to learn how to integrate it with blazor